# using button type="submit" instead of input - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, font-awesome, laravel-blade

I need to have font awesome image on button label. So i cannot use     `<input type="submit">`

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                <i class="fa-trash"></i> delete
</button>
```

View on laravel

```
{{ Form::open(array('method' 
=> 'DELETE', 'route' => array('admin.states.destroy', $value->id))) }}                       
                            {{ Form::submit(HTML::decode(FA::icon('trash')), array('class'
 => 'actions-line icon-trash','onclick'=>'return confirm("Are you sure?")')) }}
                        {{ Form::close() }}
```

This is not rendering html inside button

What is the proper way?

Comment: first one is `Next` button and second one is `Delete` button! what do you need? a button for Next or Delete?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like

```
Form::button('<i class="fa fa-star"></i> Submit', array(
            'type' => 'submit',
            'class'=> 'actions-line icon-trash',
            'onclick'=>'return confirm("Are you sure?")'
    ));
```

Tailor to your taste. The only thing to note is that the type is set to submit